# A holomorphic function with poles at all $(2n)!$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion, holomorphic-functions

During a discussion, I was asking to find a function $f$ which is holomorphic on $$\mathbb{C}\setminus \{(2n)! : n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$ Naturally, I wanted to set $$f(z) = \prod_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{z-(2n)!}$$ but this product does not converge. (Remember that $\prod_n z_n$ is convergent if and only if $\sum_n |z_n-1|$ is convergent.) So finally, I set $$f(z) = \prod_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(2n)!-z}$$ which is holomorphic on the required domain.

> First, I'd like to know if someone has a better idea to find a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{(2n)! : n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$ (If possible with "usual" functions).
>
> I would also like to know if one can get interesting informations about the function $f$ I sat. For example, can we obtain its Taylor expansion on $D(0,1)$ ?

Comment: Just a small remark: Look up Weierstraß-Factorization and Mittag-Leffler for more general settings.

Comment: why not take a sum instead of a product (with suitable coefficients to make the series converge) ? am I missing something?

Comment: something like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{1}{z-(2n)!}$

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki You don't even need to bother with coefficients, $\sum \frac{1}{z - (2n)!}$ converges locally uniformly on the entire plane.

Comment: @DanielFischer right, even better

Comment: If $\sum_n \frac{1}{|a_n|}$ converges then $f(z)=\prod_n (1-\frac{z}{a_n})$ is an entire function whose zeros are $a_n$ and $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is meromorphic with poles at $a_n$

Comment: $z\mapsto \dfrac{\sin z} z$ is an entire function that has zeros at $\pi n$ for $n\in\mathbb Z.$ And it is $$ \displaystyle \prod_{n\,\in\,\mathbb Z\,\smallsetminus\, \{0\}} \left( 1 - \frac z {n\pi} \right) = \prod_{n\,=\,1}^\infty \left( 1 - \frac {z^2}{n^2\pi^2} \right).$$ Letting the factors be $(n\pi - z)$ doesn't work because the product diverges. So that's a similar thing. $\qquad$

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki : Interesting suggestion, thank you. Do you have any suggestion to compute the Taylor expansion of this function on $D(0,1)$ ?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{z - (2n)!} = -\frac{1}{(2n)!}\cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{z}{(2n)!}} = - \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{((2n)!)^{k+1}}$$ for $\lvert z\rvert < (2n)!$. Thus $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z - (2n)!} = - \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \Biggl(\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\bigl((2n)!\bigr)^{k+1}}\Biggr)z^k$$ for $\lvert z\rvert < 2$.